# Decomposing a diagonal positive real matrix

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, numerics, mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

I would like to 'decompose' a *diagonal positive real* matrix $E$ of rank $D$ onto $\sum_{i=1}^{D}c(i)N^i$:
   $$E  = \left( 
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 &  &  &  \\
  & a &  &  \\
  &  & b &  \\
  &  &  & \ldots  \\
\end{array} \right)   \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{D}c(i)N^i$$
where 
$$ N = \left( 
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 &  &  &  \\
  & 1 &  &  \\
  &  & 2 &  \\
  &  &  & \ldots  \\
\end{array} \right) $$

and  $\bigl\{c(0), c(1), c(2), \ldots \bigr\}$ is the coeffients we want to find given $E$.  Just a note about $E$: it is well behaved and $0<a<b<\ldots$. We can also assume $E$ is such that $c(i) < c(i+1)$.

First I just re-express the problem as a set of linear equations, where $E[i]$ is the $i$th eigenvalue of the rank $D$ matrix and $D_{max}$ is the truncation of the expansion (I assume I have truncate because of numerical difficulty in solving the equations). $D$ should be of $\mathcal{O}(10^3)$:

$$  E[p] = \sum_{i=1}^{D_\max}c(i)p^i : p\in(1,\ldots,D)$$

This sounds more complicated than the rather simple problem I think it should be. Now in terms of *Mathematica* my toy attempt is as follows:

```
 d = 10; 
 Dmax = 5; 
 (* Generate matrix E *)
 evals = Table[1.25* x - 1.21*10^-5 x^2 + 10^-6 x^3 + 0*10^-8 x^7, {x, 1, d}]
 (* Decompose *)
 eqns = Table[ evals[[p]] == Sum[c[i] p^i, {i, 1, Dmax}], {p, 1, d}];
 solns = NSolve[eqns, Table[c[i], {i, 0, Dmax}], Reals]  ;
 Chop@solns
```

So as long as this is soluble, this works and gives:

```
 (* {{c[1] -> 1.25, c[2] -> -0.0000121, c[3] -> 1.*10^-6, c[4] -> 0, c[5] -> 0}} *)
```

That is as long as 0 multiples $10^{-8} x^7$. Otherwise this is not a problem to solve but to minimize (which is the case of interest).  (The `NSolve` here is just to demonstrate the idea).  Using `NMinimize` with the constrains: $c[1] > c[2] > c[3] > c[4] > c[5]$:

```
 eqns = Table[Abs[evals[[p]] - Sum[c[i] p^i, {i, 1, Dmax}] ],          {p, 1, d}];
 solns = NMinimize[{Total[eqns],  Greater @@ Table[c[i], {i, 1, Dmax}]}, Table[c[i], {i, 1, Dmax}]]
```

Which gives the bad result:

```
 (* {995.29, {c[1] -> 0.91, c[2] -> 0.468, c[3] -> 0.247, c[4] -> 0.245, c[5] -> -0.030}} *)
```

This is quite far from the result above, and it is much worse if the $10^{-8}x^7$ term is included.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this more correctly or efficiently?

Comment: You end up with a system of equations involving a Vandermonde matrix, which is fixed for a given dimension $D$. You can perhaps precompute the inverse of this and just multiply `evals` by it. I get similar results with this approach.

Comment: This sounds very interesting! Perhaps you can put up some code, because I am not sure what exactly you mean at the moment. Also, It would be nice for the code to work for an approximate decomposition, in some sense a projection of from the {N^1,N^2,..N^D} onto {N^1,N^2,..N^Dmax}. as I tried to simulate with  10^−8 * x^7

Comment: Thinking about it, do you mean: LeastSquares[ Table[ p^i ,          {p, 1, d}, {i, 1, Dmax}], evals]. That seems to work, except when I make D = 100 (It must be the large number 100^dmax). Any suggestions on how to get around this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The set of equations given by

$$e_p = \sum_{i=1}^D c_i\ p^i,\quad p\in\{1,\ldots,D\}$$

where the $e_p$ are the diagonal elements (or eigenvalues) of $\mathbf{E}$ can be written as

$$\mathbf{e} = \mathbf{c}\
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1^{D-1} \\
 1 & 2 & \ldots & 2^{D-1} \\
 \vdots &  & \ddots & \vdots \\
 1 & D & \ldots & D^{D-1}  \\
\end{array} 
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 &  &  &  \\
  & 2 &  &  \\
  &  & \ddots &  \\
  &  &  & D  \\
\end{array} 
\right)
$$

where $\mathbf{e}=\{e_1,\ldots,e_D\}$ and $\mathbf{c}=\{c_1,\ldots,c_D\}$.
Observe that the first matrix is a Vandermonde matrix that is explicitly invertible and that the two matrices are dependent only on the rank $D$. So you can precompute the inverse matrix and obtain $\mathbf{c}$ for different $\mathbf{e}$.

Taking your example above:

```
d = 10;
e = Table[1.25*x - 1.21*10^-5 x^2 + 10^-6 x^3 + 0*10^-8 x^7, {x, 1, d}];
Vinv = DiagonalMatrix[1/Range@d].LinearAlgebra`VandermondeInverse[Range@d];
Chop[e.Vinv]    
(* {1.25, -0.0000121, 1.*10^-6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

where `Vinv` is the inverse of the product of the two matrices above.

This also works when you include the $10^{-8}x^7$ term:

```
e = Table[1.25*x - 1.21*10^-5 x^2 + 10^-6 x^3 + 10^-8 x^7, {x, 1, d}];
Chop[e.Vinv]
(* {1.25, -0.0000121, 1.*10^-6, 0, 0, 0, 1.*10^-8, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Comment: Could you also say what the LinearAlgebra`VandermondeInverse[Range@d];  function does, it is undocumented. because Range@d is not a matrix but a 1D list.

Comment: @AimForClarity Why don't you try evaluating it? :) Also try ``LinearAlgebra`VandermondeMatrix@Range@d`` (for an appropriate value of `d`). Note that a square [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) is fully specified by a 1D list, and a unique inverse exists if all the elements of the 1D list are distinct.

Comment: thanks, i'll just need to pick up a nice book on it